# visual studio's intellisense not working for ajax script

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2010

i am learning AJAX. i have visual studio 2010 and in that intellisense feature is not showing the open() and send() methods of XMLHttpRequest class.

i have added jquery library files to my page and jquery is working fine but AJAX is not working.

please guide me.

here is a code snippet

```
var xmlhttp;

function loadevent()
{

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.

}
```

when i press the "." it only shows 7 standard attributes like propertyof, constructor, tostring etc.

Comment: jQuery isn't magic. You need to call the `$.ajax()` method. You're still using the JavaScript object for ajax calls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: @RUJordan : sir, can you please tell me a proper syntax for that? and what is the difference between javascript ajax and jquery ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `vsdoc` files for intellisense. Have a look at the following links...

1. ***[NuGet 1.6.0-](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.vsdoc)*** Here they have mentioned `vsdoc files for Visual Studio IntelliSense are now included in the core jquery NuGet package. As a result, this pacakge is obsolete and will not be updated past version 1.6`
2. ***[NuGet latest jQuery Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/)***
3. ***[Independently you can download it from here](http://appendto.com/jquery-vsdoc/)***

<kbd>**Hope it helps...**</kbd>